# Swift: Storyboard solution to clicking from ViewControllers to ViewController in a ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am building a App with a fixed Top Bar and some fixed Buttons at the bottom. In the middle of my MainViewController I want to have some Tables I switch in between. The ways I want to do it:

- clicking the buttons at the bottom
- clicking buttons in my tables

To solve the problem I put a ContainerView inside my MainViewController. It works for me already to switch the InsideViewControllers by clicking one of the buttons at the bottom. I solved it with Apples [Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) programmatically. By click on a button I change The childViewController of my ContainerView.

When clicking a button in my InsideViewController I am sending a message to my ParentViewController (the Container) right now. This I did by implementing a protocol and checking if my parentViewController implements it.

Now my question is if this is the optimal solution to click from ViewController to ViewController inside my ContainerView. Or is there a better way to click a button on my Table and get the next Table?

What I was thinking about is maybe possible:

A storyboard solution. I want to connect ViewControllers inside my storyboard. So that I have a button on my first view Controller and do a segue from this one to the next ViewController. If I do it just like explained the new ViewController is not filling the Container. There pops up a normal ViewController to my app. Here a example View of this idea:[image]

Is it possible or do I continue by sending messages to my parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. You can start reading [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1), specifically, the section "Configuring a Container in Interface Builder". At the initial phase of adding the Container View, you will automatically see a new UIViewController appearing there. I guess if you will want to perform transitions, you will have to `Embed In` a navigation controller that new view controller.

[image]